# dynamic pivoting for each column in master and for all dates

Tags: sql, t-sql

i have table `tbl_product_details` like :

```
create table tbl_product_details (productdate date, productname varchar(100), nav float , ncv float)



  insert into tbl_product_details 
    values('2017-10-04 00:00:00', 'UU8899', 10.23, 13.89),
    ('2017-10-05 00:00:00', 'UU8899', 12.23, 14.89)
```

and one master table where name of required pivoting column stored like.

```
 create table dynamiccols(id int , colname varchar(100))

 insert into dynamiccols
 values(1,'nav'),(1,'ncv')
```

i need to create dynamic pivoting to show pivoted data for all dates columns along with each column mentioned in  dynamiccols
 tables like :

```
productname nav~~04-10-2017 nav~~05-10-2017 ncv~~04-10-2017 ncv~~05-10-2017
UU8899      10.23               12.23           13.89           14.89
```

i have tried it but not able to make it complete dyanmic for each column in dynamiccols

---

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName_header AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName_pivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX) 
declare @kpiname varchar(100)='ncv' 

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName_header= ISNULL(@ColumnName_header + ',','') 
       + 'sum('+QUOTENAME(productdate) +') as ' ++QUOTENAME(@kpiname+'~~'+convert(varchar(11),productdate,105)),
       @ColumnName_pivot= ISNULL(@ColumnName_pivot + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(productdate)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT productdate 
FROM tbl_product_details 
where productdate between '02-oct-2017' and '05-oct-2017') AS productdate


SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'    select * 
    from (  SELECT  productname ,' +  @ColumnName_header + '
    FROM tbl_product_details        
    PIVOT(sum('+@kpiname+') 
    FOR productdate IN (' + @ColumnName_pivot + ')) AS PVTTable        
    group by productname )  '+ char(97)


    print @DynamicPivotQuery
    exec(@DynamicPivotQuery)
```